# Existence of solution of equation involving normal distribution

Tags: real-analysis, normal-distribution, roots, integral-equations

I've tried to show that the following equation has a solution:

\begin{equation*}
g(x)=\left[1-\left(2\int _{\mu}^{x}f(y)dy\right)^2\right]-8xf(x)\int _{\mu}^{x}f(y)dy=0,
\end{equation*}
where $f(x)$ is the probability density of the normal distribution and $\mu >0$ is the mean of the distribution.

Here is what I've already done (thought):

(i) $g(\mu)=1$, such that we must have $x^{\ast}>\mu$.

(ii) I've tried to show that $G(x)<0$ for some $x$, such that I could apply Intermediate value theorem, but I've failed.

(iii) Numerical simulations show that there exists an unique solution and it is higher than the mean.

Could someone give me a clue? Thank you!